# Security processing failed with reason "19" ("USERID DISABLED or RESTRICTED"). SQLSTATE=08001

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I am running into this error when trying to access db2 through my code, as well as the cloud console. I am using db2 hosted on ibm cloud.

```
Security processing failed with reason "19" ("USERID DISABLED or RESTRICTED").  SQLSTATE=08001
```

I am unable to perform sql queries, or access any of my table data through the console, or perform any admin access. I cannot figure out what the issue is let alone how to solve it. What could be my issue?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @mao, here is my finding (worked for me with a free account) for anyone who ends up here for the same problem. As suggested in discussion forums at IBM course, Applied-data-science-capstone, you need to create new service credentials for your Db2 database. If you do not have any important table in your current database, it is even safer to delete it and recreate a new Db2 either in London or Dallas region followed by new service credentials. As of today, if you use sqlalchemy package in Python, versions higher than 1.4 are incompadible so:

###### !pip uninstall sqlalchemy==1.4 -y && pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.24

To find the location of your credentials on IBM cloud check: [Connection credentials](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-db_details_cxn_creds#:%7E:text=To%20retrieve%20your%20service%20credentials,and%20credentials%20in%20JSON%20format.) or [this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ow7i.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question for stackoverflow because it is not about programming Db2. It is an operational matter for IBM.

Some people reported this symptom with accounts that were created long ago, or which failed to migrate to new versions of Db2-on-cloud , or which became expired before migrations through lack of use or lack of renewals.

If you pay for an IBM managed service, then contact IBM cloud support  to resolve such problems.

If you have a free (lite) account, currently you get no formal support. You can drop the service, and create a new service , possibly at a different data centre, using a different email address if necessary.